# MongoDB - Matching the two collections by field name

Tags: mongodb, collections, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have two collections.

collection1:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "user1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "user2"
  }
]
```

collection2:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "Info": {
      "initiatedBy": "user1"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Test LFE",
    "Info": {
      "initiatedBy": "user1"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Test uuE",
    "Info": {
      "initiatedBy": "user2"
    }
  }
]
```

I want the final result as

`user1: 2`. Because user1 created 2 records.

`user2: 1`. Because only one record was created by user2.

I used the below query to execute in Mongo Compass but was not given the exact result.

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "Info.initiatedBy",
      as: "matchedRecords"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$matchedRecords"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $sum: "$matchedRecords.fieldToCount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Please provide your suggestions to correct the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that any reason to `$unwind` the `matchedRecords` array and perform `$group`.

Instead, you can get the size of `matchedRecords` array with `$size` operator.

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "Info.initiatedBy",
      as: "matchedRecords"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      count: {
        $size: "$matchedRecords"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pvABOWVJljR)

Comment: Hi Yong, This query is not returning all the records and giving few records in a result.
Collection1 : 200+ records
Collection2 : 600+ records

Is there any reason likely to happen if localField or foreignField is nul?

Comment: Hi. Basically the result will return the same amount as Collection1. For `$lookup`, its concept is collection 1 LEFT JOIN collection 2. So the final output will be all the documents in collection with `count` either 0 or more depends on the size of `matchedRecords` array.